# Recommended on-line SQL-92 certification?

Tags: sql

I'm interested in measuring and improving (where necessary) my team's SQL-92 skills. Can anyone recommend an appropriate on-line course and/or examination?

Ideally it would be vendor-neutral, but it could also be MSSQL/Oracle specific, as long as the proprietary bits were flagged as such.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about certification, not programming.

Comment: It's not a certification site but a good online training site nonetheless: http://sqlzoo.net/

Answer (score 1):

W3Schools provides an [SQL tutorial and quiz](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp). Has anyone tried them?

I just did the quiz and it's very basic. 20 questions that I got 100% right in just over 3 minutes. I guess it's not bad for weeding people out in an initial interview.

Comment: W3Schools is known for it's bad quality and the SQL part doesn't make an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try SQL Exercises: http://www.sql-ex.ru

Comment: That site seems really good, I'll give it a closer look.